# ImportError: libmysqlclient_r.so.16

Tags: package, mysql-python, importerror

I have a problem in python 2.6. I am trying to

```
import MySQLdb
```

it will show me an error like

> ImportError: libmysqlclient_r.so.16: cannot open shared object file: No such file or directory

I tried to search a lot but couldn't find anything.

Answer (score -1):

reason behind this error is missing package for `mysql`

download a rpm file containing `libmysqlclient_r.so.16` file and make sure that file is 32/64 bit architecture depending on your OS.

install package and all done.

hope it will work for you too.